# Failed to execute the command due to sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "userUploader" is not defined

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to execute `JavaScript` from my `Java` class as

```
public class ScriptExecutor implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext ctx;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
      throws BeansException {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  public String execute(String script) throws ScriptException {
    String defaultImports = getImportPackageCommand();
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
//    engine.put("ctx", ctx);

    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("ctx", ctx);
    engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);

    final String scriptToExecute = defaultImports + script;
    System.out.println("Executing: " + scriptToExecute);
    return engine.eval(scriptToExecute).toString();
  }

  private String getImportPackageCommand() {
    final String importPackage = "importPackage(com.controller.my.cli);\n";
    return System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.8") ?
        "load(\"nashorn:mozilla_compat.js\");\n" + importPackage : importPackage;
  }
}
```

I am running this with `java 1.8`, when I run it, I get

```
Failed to execute the command due to sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "userUploader" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#2) in <Unknown source> at line number 2
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "userUploader" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#2) in <Unknown source> at line number 2
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:240)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.abc.logs.script.ScriptExecutor.execute(ScriptExecutor.java:34)
    at com.abc.logs.script.ScriptExecutorCommand.execute(ScriptExecutorCommand.java:39)
    at com.abc.logs.controller.cli.AbstractStandaloneCommand.runCliCommand(AbstractStandaloneCommand.java:18)
    at com.abc.logs.controller.cli.AbstractCliCommand.runCliCommand(AbstractCliCommand.java:42)
    at com.abc.logs.controller.cli.Cli.executeCommand(Cli.java:88)
    at com.abc.logs.controller.cli.Cli.main(LogProcessorCli.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "userUploader" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#2)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3770)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3748)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3833)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1760)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1785)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:849)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3160)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1169)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your JavaScript is referencing an undefined variable. Can you show us what exactly you are trying to execute?

Comment: It;s a Spring bean, that I try to execute. I see that during debugging though, `appContext:com.ldap.LdapUploader@625dd7ec`

Comment: I meant the JavaScript. What gets passed to the execute function just before it throws i.e. what is the value of `String script`?